# Есть ли для sublime text 3 плагин для предпросмотра SVG прямо в редакторе?

Tags: плагин, sublime-text-3

Для Sublime Text 3 есть плагин Image Preview для предпросмотра картинок.
Наводишь на адрес картинки и всплывает окошко с картинкой и другой информацией:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли такой же плагин для предпросмотра SVG, подключенных, как картинка?

```
<img class="logo" src="./img/logo.svg" alt="logo">
```